# Serializing List<T> subclass fails

Tags: serialization, dart

An object with a property `List<T>` serializes perfectly fine. However, when the property is a subclass of `List<T>`, serialization fails with

```
Caught type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'SubList' of 'value'.
```

Code:

```dart
class SubList extends ListBase<String> {
    List<String> _internal;
    SubList() : _internal = new List<String>();
    int get length => _internal.length;
    set length(int l) { _internal.length = l; }
    String operator [](int index) => _internal[index];

    void operator []=(int index, String value) {
        _internal[index] = value;
    }
}
class AnotherTestList extends Object with ListMixin<String> {
    // same implementation as above
}

class EncapsulateTest {
    SubList list;
    EncapsulateTest();
}

test("SerializeEncapsulateTest", () {
    Serialization ser = new Serialization();
    EncapsulateTest tm = new EncapsulateTest();
    tm.list = new SubList();
    var serialized = ser.write(tm);
    EncapsulateTest revived = ser.read(serialized);
    expect(revived.list, new isInstanceOf<SubList>());
});
```

error:

```
ERROR: SerializeEncapsulateTest
  Test failed: Caught type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'SubList' of 'value'.
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/dartan/test/model/serialization_test.dart 37:10                                         EncapsulateTest.list=
  dart:mirrors-patch/mirrors_impl.dart 295                                                                      _LocalInstanceMirror._invokeSetter
  dart:mirrors-patch/mirrors_impl.dart 194                                                                      _LocalObjectMirror.setField
  package:serialization/src/basic_rule.dart 394:20                                                              defaultSetter
  package:serialization/src/basic_rule.dart 383:11                                                              _NamedField.setValue
  package:serialization/src/basic_rule.dart 246:21                                                              BasicRule.inflateNonEssential.<fn>
  package:serialization/src/basic_rule.dart 539:10                                                              _FieldList.forEachRegularField
  package:serialization/src/basic_rule.dart 244:32                                                              BasicRule.inflateNonEssential
  package:serialization/src/reader_writer.dart 389:31                                                           inflateForRule.<fn>
  dart:_collection-dev/list.dart 267                                                                            ListMapView.forEach
  package:serialization/src/reader_writer.dart 388:43                                                           inflateForRule
  dart:collection/list.dart 55                                                                                  Object&ListMixin.forEach
  package:serialization/src/reader_writer.dart 358:18                                                           Reader.read
  package:serialization/serialization.dart 383:34                                                               Serialization.read
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/dartan/test/model/serialization_test.dart 98:39                                         testSerialization.<fn>
  package:unittest/src/test_case.dart 110:30                                                                    _run.<fn>
  dart:async/future_impl.dart 453                                                                               _Future._propagateToListeners.<fn>
  dart:async/zone.dart 683                                                                                      _rootRun
  dart:async/zone.dart 832                                                                                      _RootZone.run
  dart:async/future_impl.dart 445                                                                               _Future._propagateToListeners
  dart:async/future_impl.dart 303                                                                               _Future._complete
  dart:async/future_impl.dart 354                                                                               _Future._asyncComplete.<fn>
  dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weakness in the current implementation. You can do it, but it's more work than I'd like. So the default set of rules includes ListRule, which will grab anything that "is List". Sometimes that's what you want, for example, you can't really serialize an ObservableList with the things that are observing it, so it will get saved as if it were a List and then restored the same way. However, in your case that's not what you want.

The only hook available for that right now is to have another rule that grabs your subclass and add it ahead of the default. So, e.g. subclass ListRule and add it first. It would be nice to have some sort of mechanism for the "most specific" rule, or at least to be able to indicate something as a fallback rule in case no other rule wanted it.

```dart
class SublistRule extends ListRule {
  appliesTo(thing, writer) => thing is Sublist;
  inflateEssential(List state, Reader r) => new Sublist();
}

main() {
  test("SerializeEncapsulateTest", () {
    Serialization ser = new Serialization.blank()
      ..addRule(new SublistRule())
      ..addDefaultRules();
    EncapsulateTest tm = new EncapsulateTest();
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: I had created several variants of a custom rule. Adding the rule *before* the default rules did the trick.